# Calculadora em php usando botões

Tags: php

Sou novo com PHP e estou fazendo uma calculadora utilizando botões e estou tendo erro, gostaria de saber o motivo do erro, até agora só fiz até a parte de soma e subtração.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Resultado</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<?php

  $n1 = $_GET['numero1'];
  $n2 = $_GET['numero2'];
  $op = $_GET['escolha'];

    switch ($escolha){
        case = 'Soma':
            $result = $n1 + $n2;
            echo "O Resultado é: $result"; 
            break;
        case ='Subtração':
            $result = $n1 + $n2;
            echo "O Resultado é: $result"; 
            break; 
        }


?>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Formulário

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Calculado Boladonaaa</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div clas="row">

            <div clas="col-md-6">

                <form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="get"
                                          action="resultado.php">
                    <h3>Calculada</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numero1">Digite um número para calculo</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numero1" id="numero1"
                            placeholder="Digite o primeiro número">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numero2">Digite o segundo número para o calculo</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numero2" id="numero2"
                            placeholder="Digite o segundo número"><br>
                   </div>
                    <h4>Selecione a operação desejada<h4>        
                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="operacao" value="Soma" id="Soma">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="operacao" value="Subtração" id="Subtração">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"   name="operacao" value="Multiplicação" id="Multiplicação">
                    <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="operacao" value="Divisão" id="Divisão">
                  </form>         
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>








    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A página resultado.php está retornando não encontrada - 404 Error.

Comment: E, por acaso, qual é o erro?

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp64\www\projeto_calculado\resultado.php on line 24, na linha do case soma.

Comment: Esse igual não existe, vide [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php).

Answer (score 2):

Estou vendo alguns problemas no seu código:

```
$op = $_GET['escolha']; # esta jogando o escolha para a var $op
switch ($escolha) # esta usando $escolha que não existe
# case = 'Soma': # errado
case 'Soma': # correto
# seu switch falta um default:
```

Aplicando as mudanças:

```
$n1 = isset($_GET['numero1']) ? $_GET['numero1']*1 : 0 ; # verifico se o get foi passado e converto para inteiro fazendo o *1
$n2 = isset($_GET['numero2']) ? $_GET['numero2']*1 : 0 ;
$op = isset($_GET['escolha']) ? $_GET['escolha'] : 0 ;

switch ($op){ # corrigido

    case 'Soma': # corrigido
        $result = $n1 + $n2;
        echo "O Resultado é: $result"; 
        break;

    case 'Subtração': # corrigido
        $result = $n1 - $n2; # corrigido
        echo "O Resultado é: $result"; 
        break; 

    default: # adicionado
        echo "Sem resultado";
}
```

Edição:

Como comentado por @AndersonCarlosWoss, você pode converter para int/float utilizando as funções do php `intval` e `floatval`

```
# esta linha esta fazendo o mesmo que o if abaixo
$n1 = isset($_GET['numero1']) ? $_GET['numero1']*1 : 0;

#  $var = <checagem> ? <valor caso verdade> : <valor caso falso>;


if( isset($_GET['numero1']) )
{
    $n1 = $_GET['numero1'] * 1;
    # O vezes (*) 1 era para transformar o valor para inteiro 
    # voce pode utilizar intval( $_GET['numero1'] ) para inteiro
    # ou ainda floatval( $_GET['numero1'] ) para float 
    # fiz isso pq o valor esta vindo por GET então acredito que nesse momento ele é string
    # mas aparentemente quando você aplicar a soma ou a subtração ...
    # ele vai tratar como numero como o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse em seu comentário
}
else
{
    $n1 = 0;
}
```

*@Lucas: Valeu mesmo, fiz as alterações, funcionou porem agora só esta somando mesmo quando clico em subtração*
Acho que essa parte pode esta causando o problema

```
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="operacao" value="Soma" id="Soma">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="operacao" value="Subtração" id="Subtração">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"   name="operacao" value="Multiplicação" id="Multiplicação">
<input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="operacao" value="Divisão" id="Divisão">
```

Uma solução seria colocar o `type='radio'` e criar um outro `input` para fazer o submit, algo como no exemplo abaixo.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="operacao" value="Soma" id="Soma">
    Soma
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="operacao" value="Subtração" id="Subtração">
    Subtração
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="operacao" value="Multiplicação" id="Multiplicação">
    Multiplicação
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="operacao" value="Divisão" id="Divisão">
    Divisão
</label>

<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
```

Comment: O que `+$_GET['numero2']*1` faz?

Comment: Erro meu, era para converter para inteiro, porem não lembro se o `php` aceita a converção `+$var`

Comment: ai acabei trocando de ultima hora para `$var*1`

Comment: Ao meu ver, usar `intval` ou `floatval` ficaria mais explícito do que multiplicar por "um valor aleatório", isso desconsiderando o fato que o PHP já trata *strings* numéricas como números, então a conversão passa a ser desnecessária.

Comment: Valeu mesmo, fiz as alterações, funcionou porem agora só esta somando mesmo quando clico em subtração

Comment: E eu não entendi mt bem esse  "? $_GET['numero1']*1 : 0 ;" que foi adicionado ao lado das variavéis

Comment: @LucasAlmeida fiz uma alteração na resposta, verifica se atende

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de case = 'Soma', o certo é case 'Soma'

```
        switch ($variable) {
        case 'value':
            # code...
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Vlw, já corrigi

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch ($escolha){
        case 'Soma':
            $result = $n1 + $n2;
            echo "O Resultado é: $result"; 
            break;
        case 'Subtração':
            $result = $n1 + $n2;
            echo "O Resultado é: $result"; 
            break; 
        }
```

Seu problema está no case você está utilizando atribuição e a sintaxe é como segue no código acima!